# Amazon Mosquitos - ArrayIndexOutOfBounds

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to make a little Java program.

The program has an input of 3 ints: S: the starting mosquitoes, K: the number of children every mosquito makes, and N: the number of days we "investigate".

Each mosquito in the Amazon lives 1 day. Day 0, we begin with S mosquitoes. The one day that each mosquito lives, it does only two things. First, it attacks one person. Immediately after the attack, the mosquito gives birth to K mosquitoes and then dies.

The output of the program must be the number of humans that will be attacked in the end of the N days.

For example, for inputs (1,2,12) the output must be 8191 (1+2+4+8+...+4096).

My attempt is the following:

```
public class AmazMosq {

    public static int reproduction(int starting, int children, int days) {

        int[] mosquitos = new int[days];
        mosquitos[0] = starting;

        int bites = starting;

        for (int i = 1; i <= days; i++) {
            mosquitos[i] = mosquitos[i-1] * children;

            bites += mosquitos[i];
        }

        return bites;

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Enter the number of starting mosquitos:");
        int starting = IOUtil.readInt();

        System.out.println("Enter the number of children each mosquito makes everyday:");
        int children = IOUtil.readInt();

        System.out.println("Enter the number of days:");
        int days = IOUtil.readInt();

        System.out.println(reproduction(starting, children, days));

    }

}
```

Where IOUtil.readInt() is a function to read input Ints.

However, I am getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 12
    at AmazMosq.reproduction(AmazMosq.java:11)
    at AmazMosq.main(AmazMosq.java:34)
```

What does it mean and what did I do wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: The javadoc is usually helpful in understanding what exceptions mean: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= days; i++) {
```

You initialize the array like this:

```
int[] mosquitos = new int[days];
```

So you can access to elements between 0 and `days - 1`. You're accessing to element `mosquitos[days]` inside the `for` loop, which is the cause of the problem, specifically here:

```
mosquitos[i] = mosquitos[i-1] * children;
//^   here ^
bites += mosquitos[i];
//       ^    here   ^
```

Change it to

```
for (int i = 1; i < days; i++) {
```

Or even better, to this:

```
for (int i = 1; i < mosquitos.length; i++) {
```

Comment: Thank you! I got it. However, for the answer to be correct, I figured that my mistake was when intializing the array and not in the loop. The length of mosquitos had to be days + 1 and not days.

Comment: @pavlos55 that's another solution to the problem. Still, it's better to use `array.length` as upper bound rather than another variable.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use `mosquitos[i]` when `i <= days`. As `days` is the length of `mosquitos`, it throws `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when `i == days`.

// Was answered already..